# Sub Navigation drop down problems

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

Im creating a navigation with three levels of sub navigation elements.

At the moment its working fine when you get to the third level but it is only displaying one subcategory where I want it to display multiple sub categories.

Im unsure as to why its not showing this up and must be a problem with the way I have designed and developed it.

I have included a JS Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/e52u02bL/4/

```
HTML

<body>
<div class="nav">
<ul class="nav-primary test">
    <li><a href="#">Household</a>
        <ul class="test">
            <li><a href="#">Living Room</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bedroom</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Living Room</a>
                <ul class="thrdLvl">
                    <li><h4>Heading</h4></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="thrdLvl">
                    <li><h4>Heading</h4></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Hardware</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Wedding List</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>


CSS

.nav {
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position:relative;
  }

  .nav ul {
    background: #FFF;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0 20px;
    margin: 0;

  }

  ul.test li {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .nav ul li a {
    color:#333333;
    display:block;
    padding:0px 40px;
    text-decoration:none;
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
  }

  .nav ul li:hover {
    background: #3B95D3;
  }


  .nav ul li:hover > a{
    color:#FFFFFF;
  }

  .nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
  }

  .nav ul ul {
    background: #FFF;
    padding:0;
    display:none;
     width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0px;
  }

  .nav ul ul ul {
    background: #3B95D3;
    display:none;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0px;
  }

  .nav ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
    background-color:red;
    padding-top:;
    width: 33.33333%;
  }


  div > h4 {color:#FFF; padding-left: 38px;}

  ul.thrdLvl > li{
      display:block;
      max-width:100px;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
    .nav{
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        padding: 0 2em;
    }

    .nav ul {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .nav ul li {
        width: 100%;
    }

  }
```

Many Thanks,

Robert.

Comment: Hi Robert, I think the reason is that CSS is not referring to all <ul> tags after (line 40 on CSS). It would only refer to the first. If you change the class name of one of the .thrdLvl's it works ~

Comment: Actually, I take that back. It's an absolute positioning problem. The thrdLvl's are positioned on top of each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is absolute positioning (the third layers were imposing themselves on top of one another). In absolute positioning, there is no floating of elements. As a result, you generally have to specify an offset left to achieve your required affect. Perhaps this example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/domslee/e52u02bL/21/

CSS:

```
.nav ul ul {
  left: 0px; /*Removing this fixes aligning issue*/
}
.nav ul ul ul {
  background: #3B95D3;
  display:none;
  width: 200px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0px;
}

.nav ul ul ul:nth-child(2) { /*Using n-th child to specify offset for second child*/
  left: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I thought this might have been the case will I have to do this for every sub menu as in the third level navigation there may be 5-10 subcategorys... not too sure if this is the best solution I am going for. Thanks for all your help really appreciate it.

Comment: You might be able to use a wrapper or something on the third level... let me try a couple of things I'll get back to you

Comment: Ok brilliant thank you continuing to have a look at it also, Robert.

Comment: You can try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Domination/e52u02bL/23/

However it has issues on mobile view in terms of overlapping elements (absolute position issues)

Comment: That seems to work a lot better now! I thought it would will have to solve those only problem I have now would be that it only spans across two where I would like it to flow within my container I have updated the JS Fiddle again https://jsfiddle.net/e52u02bL/24/ really appreciate your help on this was an annoying bug that I couldn't seem to solve so thank you.

Comment: I've added a script that sets the width of the third level depending on how many columns there are: https://jsfiddle.net/Domination/e52u02bL/25/

You'll need jQuery in your final HTML, include this under <head> tag:

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Also modify line 66 of the CSS if you want to change the width of each columns ~ peace

Comment: Hello, that is basically it finished thats brilliant thank you! dont mean to be a pain there was one more issue with it when you hover over household and then the living room after bedroom is there anyway that i can make every sub level navigation start at the at the very start of the container? The navigation is a big one so was trying to make it as accessible as possible. Thank you very much, Robert.

Comment: Do you mean all the way to the left?

Comment: Yes basically just when a user hovers over the 2nd or whatever third level navigation that it will open up from the left across the page.

Comment: Ah I see, so something like [this?](https://jsfiddle.net/Domination/e52u02bL/27/)

If that's all good and all please mark as answer and upvote for completeness :)

Comment: Thats basically it mate will mark as the answer and upvote too! just one more lol! can i not automatically even if there is one thirld level sub nav make it stretch full width of any screen size? Ill mark that for you now thank you so much for all your help on this. Robert.

Comment: You mean like setting a max-width attribute on nav or something like that? Sorry I don't really understand the question.... Can you restate it differently?

Comment: The likes of the fix on the household third level where it goes to the left can I make this automatically stretch the full screen even if theres only 2 sub categorys? Its pretty hard to navigate if theres only a few sub categories, Hope this help clears up what I mean.